# Starter exercises on scientific computing (Python)

Tags: python, scientific-computing

I am interested in learning the basics of scientific computing, but sadly in my daily life I don't encounter problems or situations in which I get to code something to solve a mathematical problem (Or any problem whatsoever, other than the basic programming things we are asked to do).

I know the basics of python and I'm not worried about it since I can always learn what I need on the go, but I need a resource (A book, website or mailing list will do) with problems and exercises I can use to start working with the kind of situations I could encounter if I decide to work in this in the future.

I've looked around but I haven't seen anything aimed for people knowing programming but not knowing the specific details of scientific computing, just advanced things I don't understand at the moment.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as it is asking for an off-site resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I first started learning to program I used Project Euler. It is a series of challenging mathematical/computer programming problems that will require logical and mathematical insights to solve. Although mathematics will help you arrive at elegant and efficient methods, the use of a computer and programming skills will be required to solve most problems. The problems themselves are interesting, and they gradually increase in difficulty.

Be careful though - it can become quite addictive!

Here's the link: https://projecteuler.net

Answer (score 0):

You might try [About Project Euler] (http://projecteuler.net/) and [Problems](http://projecteuler.net/problems)

The problem are interesting and can be done using different languages. Since the problems have different complexities, and the different languages may allow better (or not as good) programming solutions, this would seem to be a good site to study.